# Search for specific email ids containing specific string using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python. I have a string containing many email ids and normal words. I want to get the count of number of email ids containing a specific word. Currently I am using a regex to filter out words containing the string and another regular expression on this list to filter out email ids. Just wanted to know if there is a better way to do this!

example:

Str1 : this fet@dmail.com is infet a string which is assosiated with get@dmail.com and net@dfet.com.

Str2: fet

Program should return count as 2
1. fet@dmail.com
2. net@dfet.com

This is the code I am currently using.. I am creating a list of strings containing str2 and verifying if it is a email id...

```
text_to_search = ".*(" + word_to_be_searched.lower() + ").*"
regex = re.compile(text_to_search)
lister = [m.group(0) for l in row_value[column_index].lower().split( ) for m in       [regex.search(l)] if m]

for li in lister:
    if re.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._%-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", li):
        match_count = match_count + 1
```

Comment: just compile this regex : http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html :)

Comment: It's difficult to know what's a "better way" if we don't see what way  you are doing it now. What are your two current regular expressions?  What is your code like that invokes them?

Answer (score 0):

Please run code below .it will solve your problem

```
import re
regex = re.compile(("([a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`"
"{|}~-]+)*(@|\sat\s)(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?(\.|"
"\sdot\s))+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)"))
email_iter = (email[0] for email in re.findall(regex, str1) if not   email[0].startswith('//'))
email_collec = []
for email in email_iter:
   email_collec.append(email)
count = 0
str2 = "fet"
for i in range(len(coll)):
    if str2 in coll[i]:
        count+=1
print count
```